# replace punctuation with nothing

Tags: python, regex, string

```
>>> import re
>>> a="what is. your. name? It's good"
>>> b=re.findall(r'\w+',a)
>>> b
['what', 'is', 'your', 'name', 'It', 's', 'good']
```

The above results in splitting `It's` to `['It','s']` I dont want that.

I want to just replace  it with nothing i.e. `It's` will be `Its`. Same applies to all the punctuation. 
How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm confused why you'd ever want to translate `It's` into `Its`, they're two different words. the `'` is not a punctuation mark.

Comment: Are you trying to remove punctuation and _then_ split the sentence into words? i.e. from the sentence `"what is. your. name? It's good"` do you want to produce the list `['what', 'is', 'your', 'name', 'Its', 'good']`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you compelled to use regex? This task can easily ne accomplished by using [str.translate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [string.punctuation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) as the `deletechars`

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> a="what is. your. name? It's good"
>>> a.translate(None, punctuation)
'what is your name Its good'
```

If you are compelled to use regex, another option for you would be

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> r = re.compile(r'[{}]+'.format(re.escape(punctuation)))
>>> r.sub('', a)
'what is your name Its good'
```

**But, I would still suggest you to reconsider the design. Using Regex for this task is an overkill.**

Comment: And finally split it.

Comment: @aIKid: I am trying to stick to the actual problem. `replace punctuation with nothing`

Comment: m compelled to use regex only

Comment: @Jarvis what are you actually trying to achieve? You've asked this in another around-about way already from your previous question... I can't help but feel you're not properly defining what you're trying to achieve, and we're going to get more posts, each a tiny bit different with problems you're having that aren't even anything to do with what you really want :)

Comment: how to convert to list?

Comment: @JonClements m doing pattern matching and sentiment analysis so regex is the key to it.

Comment: @jarvis just to check - are you aware of `nltk` and its tokenizers and analysis abilities?

Comment: @JonClements yes I am aware of nltk but not its analysis abilities

Answer (score 0):

To match any word character and a single quoted comma `'` *if there is any.*:

```
import re
string = "Many cook's were involved and many cooked pre-season food"
punctaution = re.findall(r"\w+([\-_.!~*'()])\w+",string)

for i in punctaution:
    string = re.sub(i,'',string)

print string
```

Output:

```
Many cooks were involved and many cooked preseason food
```

Comment: You should catch the spaces instead. This doesn't transform "it's" into "its"

Comment: that did not strip `'`

Comment: if word is 'pre-season' the above regex does pre,season but it should be preseason. the question was to replace punctuation with nothing